# Is it safe to take a shower outside during a thunderstorm?

Tags: safety, lightning

Recently I was camping in the local mountains and while showering a storm blew in so I took a shower in a thunderstorm. Some people said it was very dangerous. The showers were basic structures outside.

Is it safe to take a shower outside during a thunderstorm?

Comment: Is it safe to be outside during a thunderstorm in general? There's always a risk, and yes, that risk increases if you stand next to or under a lightning rod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the basic principles of lightning safety is that **you don't want to be the highest thing** around and **you don't want to be under something that is the highest thing around.**

For example [only one group](https://rrfw.org/RaftingGrandCanyon/Lightning) has ever been struck while floating the Colorado through the Grand Canyon, but multiple people have been struck either on the rim or while sheltering under trees on the top.

Given that shower heads are usually higher than people, I would not want to be standing underneath one during a thunderstorm.

Comment: See [Rafting Grand Canyon](https://rrfw.org/RaftingGrandCanyon/Lightning).

Comment: @ab2 Interesting, the info I had stopped at 2012

Comment: What about the electrical charge moving through the pipes (if metal) and/or the water? would a shower in basement, connected to a water tower on a hill top, be as dangerous as standing on the hill top?

Comment: @JamesJenkins I don't know

Comment: @JamesJenkins No, the water tower and the pipes leading to your house are thoroughly grounded. The danger of using an indoor shower is from direct/very close strikes to the house that can induce current into the home's wiring and metal plumbing.

Comment: @CareyGregory That should be "No, _if_ the water tower and the pipes leading to your house are thoroughly grounded, and they should be and probably are." I think. Is every situation grounded? I have seen some people pipe water from their reserve on a hill with PVC, and I assume they then pipe it out to a septic or leech field again with PVC. I did not think PVC conducted electricity, so then it would be just the water running through an insulator, yes?

Comment: @CareyGregory And a quick follow up to my previous comment: top Google hit says "PVC does not conduct electricity and is therefore an excellent material to use for electrical applications such as insulation sheathing for cables."

Comment: @Aaron The water tower itself is going to be metal and it's going to be sitting on metal legs attached to the ground. The main pipe leading from that water tower is extremely unlikely to be PVC. And in any case, the sheer distance will protect you. Fresh water, incidentally, is a poor conductor.

Comment: @CareyGregory Actually, the specific setup that I had in mind when I commented was one where the "tower" was a very large barrel up on a steep hillside, and I think the number of people making such DIY setups is increasing. Still, I do not know what the barrel in that specific case was made of, and your mentioned bit about fresh water and distance probably outweighs the rest as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say slightly dangerous, and probably more dangerous than other locations. You wish to avoid two things in thunderstorms. Places that are higher than the local area (50m-ish area) and "electrical earth".

A shower is a superb electrical earth, metal structure, with a better connection to "earth" than most protective earth setups. Just imagine the miles of pipes running below.

A shower is generally higher than you, but if the said shower was just next to the eiffel tower it wouldn't be much of a concern. Hard to say in your case. But I would probably, as a rule, avoid outdoor showers in a thunder storm. There is also the chance that there would be arcing in and between the shower pipes due to a lightning hit elsewhere, if it hit the water pipes. But now we are in the "really unlucky" part of the probability chart.